# razor view intellisence broken when using System.Web.MVC 5.2.2.0 and its working fine when using System.web.Mvc 5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
   <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
 </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
 <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

 <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
   <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
   <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
   <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
  </namespaces>
 </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Everything builds, however it breaks intellisence on all .cshtml razor pages:

The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

However When I set the host factoryType version to 5.0.0.0 intellisence starts working.

Can anyone please Help

Comment: Is there a `system.web > compilation > assemblies block` at the of the file?